# Removing disks with gcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, persistent-volumes

**Trying to remove disks with the gcloud cli, I want to do something like this:**

`gcloud compute disks delete $(gcloud compute disks list --filter="labels=(some-label)")`

**The gcloud cli outputs:**

The following disks will be deleted:

- [10] in [europe-west4-a]
- [30] in [europe-west4-a]
- [8] in [europe-west4-a]
- [LOCATION] in [europe-west4-a]
- [LOCATION_SCOPE] in [europe-west4-a]
- [NAME] in [europe-west4-a]
- [READY] in [europe-west4-a]
- [SIZE_GB] in [europe-west4-a]
- [STATUS] in [europe-west4-a]
- [TYPE] in [europe-west4-a]
- [europe-west4-a] in [europe-west4-a]
- [disk1] in [europe-west4-a]
- [disk2] in [europe-west4-a]
- [disk3] in [europe-west4-a]
- [disk4] in [europe-west4-a]
- [disk5] in [europe-west4-a]
- [disk6] in [europe-west4-a]
- [pd-standard] in [europe-west4-a]
- [zone] in [europe-west4-a]
  Do you want to continue (Y/n)?

**The command** `gcloud compute disks list --filter="labels=(some-label)` **yields:**

disk1  europe-west4-a  zone            10       pd-standard  READY

disk2  europe-west4-a  zone            30       pd-standard  READY

disk3  europe-west4-a  zone            8        pd-standard  READY

disk4  europe-west4-a  zone            8        pd-standard  READY

disk5  europe-west4-a  zone            8        pd-standard  READY

disk6  europe-west4-a  zone            8        pd-standard  READY

**My question is, what does all the other fields mean, in the first command? Will it only remove the disks thats intended?**

Answer (score 0):

the correct command to delete disk is
**gcloud compute disks delete my-disk --zone=us-east1-a**
replace value with your disk and zone.

If you want to just remove disk from VM instance and dont want to delete, use below command.
**gcloud compute instances detach-disk INSTANCE_NAME --disk=DISK_NAME**